# Creating a Reveal Menu

Tags: android

I wanted to create a Reveal Menu in Android just like that of Jquery mobile.
I wanted the main FrameLayout to slide to the left by 30% there by revealing another Layout behind it, which would be the menu layout.

The coding of the sliding FrameLayout was successful; that is when i click on the menu botton it side to the left 30% away.
The problem i am encountering is that when it slides to the left, the menu button stop responding at its current position but it respond at its initial position whereas the menu button has move with the framelayout by 30% to the left

here are my code

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/act_menu"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.thankgod.slidemenu.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/act_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.thankgod.slidemenu.MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/Dark">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

                <Button
                    android:text="@string/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button" />

                <Button
                    android:text="@string/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.thankgod.slidemenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int page = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       /* requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);*/

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                move();
            }
        });
    }
    public void move() {
        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.act_main);
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide);
        frameLayout.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

animation file slide.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="20%"
        android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on the menu button again it calls the move method again but it cannot move by another 30% so it seems like not moving use the below code.

```
public String a = "0"; //declare this globally at the top.
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
if(a.equals("0")
{
move();
}
else
{
// do what you want to do by clicking on the menu button once it is moved by 30%
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Menu button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
a = "1";                 
}
});
```